# How to properly handle exceptions in ManagedServiceFactories?

Tags: java, osgi

The OSGi ConfigurationAdmin specification mentions that implementations of `ManagedService` and `ManagedServiceFactory` may signal an invalid incoming configuration by throwing a `ConfigurationException`. Yet, apart from this statement, the spec is silent on how the various actors should handle the situation, and most importantly, what should be the state of the environment after such an exception.

For example, suppose that a `ManagedServiceFactory` currently has a service instance (lets say service.pid=example.12345) with a valid set of properties; that service instance is published by the factory into the service registry. Then, the factory is informed of a configuration update for that service instance; however, on verification, the update method determine that incoming properties are invalid. Based on the spec, the factory should therefore throw a `ConfigurationException`.

But then, if nothing else is done, the environment remains in an unstable state: there is now a published service in the registry based on a configuration that no longer exists; consequently, whenever the `ManagedServiceFactory` service gets restarted (for example because of a bundle update or a whole framework restart), it will not be possible to reinstantiate that service, its former valid configuration having been lost. This breaks the persistence paradigm of the Configuration Admin subsystem, and pose severe issues regarding the stability of some OSGi environment.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way for the initial configurator bundle to detect that its configuration change caused a ConfigurationException, making it hardly possible in general to restore a stable configuration from that place. It seems to me that it would be more appropriate, in such situation, for the ConfigurationAdmin to (persistently) restore the previously valid configuration, but there is unfortunately no mention of such behaviour in the spec, and I don't see any trace of such mechanism in Felix's implementation.

Given these facts, it seems that the only possibility to maintain the stability of the environment would be for a `ManagedServiceFactory` implementation to first unregister and destroy existing service instances for which it has received invalid configuration properties, and only after that, throw the mandated `ConfigurationException`. This would effectively result in the same environment state as what would be if the framework was relaunched at that point. Similarly, a `ManagedService` implementation should handle an invalid configuration by first entirely restoring its default configuration, and then throw a `ConfigurationException`.

So, how exactly should errors in `ManagedService` and `ManagedServiceFactories` configuration updates be handled? Is my understanding correct? From what I see out there in example/open source implementations of `ManagedService` and `ManagedServiceFactory`, this aspect seems to be totally ignored by most developers. Does the spec provides any clarification on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy is to log it as an error and pray it will be solved soon. The purpose of the Configuration Exception is to provide detailed information to the devops so it can be corrected quickly.

The strategies you describe are imho so hopelessly complex and open ended that they tend to create more problems then they ever can solve. Someone made a mistake to create wrong configuration, the only solution is to fix that configuration. I find that in general systems that handle these exceptional case to become very fragile. Once something is wrong, you're in an infinite space and software is extremely bad in reasoning about things you don't know about.

So unless you have  some very specific use cases I do not think it can, nor should it, have a general solution.

Comment: I can't agree with the "log it and pray it will be solved" strategy. Some of my OSGi applications are deployed as embedded machine installed at our customer's site. In this context, "system operators" basically designate some local user with little more than basic technical knowledge. Expecting them to properly survey logs for errors every time they make some configuration update is a much too high burden and eventual errors will most likely go undetected. Having the system appears to work at first, but fail to restart at a later time, when the user is no longer around, is unacceptable...

Comment: As for the strategies I describe, they are actually very simple and predictable. They do not try to repair invalid configurations, but simply to get the system out of the grey zone (that is, the system appears to work fine but would fail to reboot), either by restoring the previously valid configuration or by resetting the `MangedService[Factory]` to the same state it would be if the system was rebooted at that moment, thus making configuration issues immediately visible to the system administrator.

Comment: I agree however that there is hardly a one-size-fit-all solution to this problem. Anyway, I posted the question here just to make sure I had not missed some key points and get other developers experience regarding this problem. Thanks for sharing. I will repost the question to the osgi-dev mailing list though: I think it would be desirable for some general recommandations on the subject to be formalized...

Answer (score 0):

In general there are three strategies to handle this:

1. Rejecting the invalid configuration but keeping the previous state
2. Rejecting the invalid configuration and destroy the current state as if there was no configuration before
3. Rejecting invalid values, apply valid values as much as possible

What to choose, an wheather you descide to throw an exception, print a warning to the log, send an e-mail or bring up a popup heavyly depends on your system and use cases.

For example if you have an UI and the user can change the config you can simply save the old config and if you detect an error you can ask the user to either correct or revert the configuration.

Even better, you can describe the Configuration requirements with the [MetaTypeService](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/metatype/MetaTypeService.html) so you can validate the config before apply it.

If you have a set of config files, you better make a backup before so you can revert :)